# C++ Standard Deviation assignment need help correcting error

Tags: c++, standards, standard-deviation

Trying to write a program that uses an array to calculate standard deviation. 
It keeps giving me an error:

> "LNK2019  unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int
>   __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)  ConsoleApplication7777  C:\Users\Gregory\Desktop\ConsoleApplication7777\ConsoleApplication7777\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)    1"

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double standard_Deviation(double x[], int n);

//Main Function here
void Main()
{
    //declare variables here
    double x[100];
    double sDeviation;
    int i;
    int n;

//input number values here
cout << "Enter n value";
cin >> n;

//input array values here
cout << "Enter values:" << endl;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> x[i];
//call standard deviation function
sDeviation = standard_Deviation(x, n);

//outputting standard deviation
cout << "Standard Deviation:" << sDeviation << endl;
//give it time to think
system("pause");

}

double standard_Deviation(double x[], int n)
{
double sd = 0;
double mean=0;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    mean = mean + x[i];
mean = mean / n;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    sd = sd + pow((x[i] - mean), 2);
sd = sd / n;
sd = sqrt(sd);
return sd;
return mean;
} //end of standard deviation
```

Comment: `main` is spelled with lower case m and has return type `int`

Comment: change `void Main()` to `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

Attend case-sensitivity of C and C++; the main routine the linker looks for is

```
int main() {/**/}
```

not

```
void Main(){/* ... */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
void Main()
```

with

```
int main()
```

Applications require a `main` function (that has `int` return type) and that is what the linker is complaining about as you have not provided one due to your typo with an upper case `M`.